# python need help to extract pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

From the following list, i am trying to extract only digits(ints & floats) & versions nums (only separated by dots).

```
[u'3.1.1', u'3.2', u'3.1.2', u'3', u'3.3.0', u'3.3.1-1', u'3.2.2', u'latest']
```

Tried the following code. Its not taking out 3.3.1-1. Need help with regex. 
Also is there any fastest way to do it?

```
 def myfunc(self, img_list):
    ret = list()
    for i in img_list:
        try:
            if re.match("([\d.]+)", i):
                ret.append(i)
            elif float(i):
                ret.append(i)
        except Exception as e:
            display.vvv("Error: %s" % str(e))
            pass

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is one way to go. You can accomplish the same using filter

```
>>> lst = [u'3.1.1', u'3.2', u'3.1.2', u'3', u'3.3.0', u'3.3.1-1', u'3.2.2', u'latest']
>>> list(filter(lambda s: all(c.isdigit() or c == "." for c in s), lst))
['3.1.1', '3.2', '3.1.2', '3', '3.3.0', '3.2.2']
```

Comment: This will miss cases like `3.3..4` and `3.3.`.

Comment: @FoxanNg  **trying to extract only digits(ints & floats) & versions nums (only separated by dots).**

Comment: @XeroSmith Thank you.

Comment: @XeroSmith By `miss` I mean you're treating those as version number also, which is **not**.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using comprehension:

```
lst = [u'3.1.1', u'3.2', u'3.1.2', u'3', u'3.3.0', u'3.3.1-1', u'3.2.2', u'latest']
results = [i for i in lst if i.replace('.', '').isdigit()]
print results
```

output:

```
[u'3.1.1', u'3.2', u'3.1.2', u'3', u'3.3.0', u'3.2.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a list comprehension.

```
lst = [u'3.1.1', u'3.2', u'3.1.2', u'3', u'3.3.0', u'3.3.1-1', u'3.2.2', u'latest']
print([e for e in lst if ''.join(e.split('.')).isdigit()])
```

Prints:

```
['3.1.1', '3.2', '3.1.2', '3', '3.3.0', '3.2.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all . in the string and check if remaining characters are digits.

```
def myfunc(self , img_list):
    ret = list()
    for i in img_list:
        if '.' in i and i.replace('.','').isdigit():
            ret.append(i)
    return ret
```

Comment: Ok, I have added another condition to check if . exists. That should handle it.

Comment: Ah, I see, it might be expected. Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, your answer is much better than the one accepted (Xero's).